# Update Testcase status using Jira Rest Java Client API

Tags: jira-rest-java-api

I am using this version:

```
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6</version>
```

And I am creating TestExecution issues, then I add Testcases and now I want to update the status of the testcases.
This is the method I am using to update the status field:

```
IssueInuput issueInput = new IssueInputBuilder().setFieldValue(fieldId, fieldValue).build();
Promise<Void> promise = jiraRestClient.getIssueClient()
        .updateIssue(issueKey, issueInput);
promise.claim();
```

And I have tried several things to update the status of the testcase:

```
jiraRestClient.updateIssue(testcase, Constants.TEST_RUN_STATUS, "PASS");

jiraRestClient.updateIssue(testcase, Constants.TEST_RUN_STATUS, 
                ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("value", "PASS"));

jiraRestClient.updateIssue(testcase, Constants.TEST_RUN_STATUS, 
                ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("id", "0"));
```

But none of the seem to work.
Is there any way to achieve this from Java? Or am I getting something completely wrong.
For all three attempts I get this error:

```
 RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(500), errorCollections=[]}
 ...
 Caused by: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
```